# Pause on hover Simulation of next button in jquery

Tags: jquery, caroufredsel

i was wondering, how to pause with mouse on hover simulation of ''next'' button?

I have slider, with specific configured next/prev buttons, and i can't active 'auto' function because 'auto' sliding cant be configured the way a need (or i don't know how).

I have simulated ''next'' button called #grid-next like this:

```
function simulateClick(){
    $('#grid-next').click();
};

setInterval(simulateClick, 2000);
```

I need to pause that simulation when i put mouse on  slider.****

(I know how to configure regular pauseOnHover, but this is too specific for me, and i don't know how)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function simulateClick(){
    $('#grid-next').click();
};

var triggerclick;

triggerclick = setInterval(simulateClick, 2000);

$('#yourslider').mouseenter(function() {
    clearInterval(triggerclick);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    triggerclick = setInterval(simulateClick, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you all 3 for help, everything works, and i used Alex solution bc he wrote it first :D.. i would make vote, but system don't allow me. I have 1 more problem, with this slider on some browsers not showing some customizations i made. But maybe its a theme bug i am using, bc on some computers is looking great, and on some don't. :))) (lot of work to do yet) Thanks guys :))

Comment: thats just the nature of web dev, it looks different on all browsers! :D good luck

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `clearTimeout` function to clear the timer. 
When calling `setInterval` you save the returnvalue and use that as an argument in `clearTimeout`

Remember to make the var globally available

```
var t;
function startTimer()
{
    t = setInterval(simulateClick, 2000);
}

function stopTimer()
{
     clearInterval(t);
}

function simulateClick()
{
    console.log("Simulate click");
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Fizk/ykdgLmau/ for working example :)

Answer (score 0):

Much like Alex's answer but using hover() you can use callbacks for mouseenter and mouseleave:

```
function simulateClick(){
    $('#grid-next').click();
};

var triggerclick;

triggerclick = setInterval(simulateClick, 2000);

$( "#yourslider" ).hover(function() {
       clearInterval(triggerclick);
   }, function() {
         triggerclick = setInterval(simulateClick, 2000);
   }
 );
```